# ipconfig/renew and reserved ip address - How it works?

Tags: networking, dhcp, ip-address, windows-server-2012-r2, ipconfig

I'm trying to understand something.

Let's say we have a windows server with a static IP. Its IP is reserved in the DHCP, etc. Everything's good.

If I run ipconfig/release then ipconfig/renew, will it get a different IP?
(suppose that the next available IP -x.15- is not the reserved one -x.200)

Thanks,
Iswaren

Comment: If you have the IP reserved in the DHCP server, why would you think it would get a different IP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key detail here is that `ipconfig /release` does not have the ability to remove any corresponding IP address reservation that may exist at the DHCP server.

The only way to obtain a different IP address would be to either manually assign a static IP on the client or to change/remove the IP address reservation from the DHCP server. Avoid the first option if possible.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly the unknown part. Since there is a reserved IP, does /release "remove" somehow the reservation and can another computer get this reserved IP. I read so much on internet that I was not sure the mechanic behind the DHCP service. Thanks again Mr Ethernet!

Answer (score 2):

When a computer requests an IP address, and is set to get the address from DHCP, it will provide its MAC address to the DHCP server as part of the request. If the DHCP server sees that there is a reservation of an IP address associated with that MAC address, it will provide the reserved IP address. Therefore, `IPCONFIG /RELEASE` followed by `IPCONFIG /RENEW` will cause the computer to receive the same (reserved) IP address.

Comment: Yeah, I was pretty sure about this but thanks for confirmation :)